# Using Visual Studio, how can I reference a SharePoint 2010 site collection outside of the development machine?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, spsite

I am creating a custom web service which needs to reference a specific site collection on our SharePoint 2010 farm.

The web service is on a development machine not part of the farm (although SharePoint 2010 is installed on it), so using the following doesn't work:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
```

`"url"` in this case is the url to the existing SharePoint 2010 farm, hosted externally to this development machine.

Is there a method to 'talk' to the existing SharePoint 2010 farm outside of the development environment i am using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are outside of SharePoint farm, the ***Client Object Model*** is the only way to talk with SharePoint.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535451(v=office.14).aspx

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
```

Instead of above, you can use

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

> Almost every ***Server Object Model*** has an equivalent ***Client Object
>   Model***

---

**Few more things**

Assemblies of Client Object Model can be found in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/). In the package manager console paste following

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
```

Do not forget to specify authentication credentials.

```
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

Do a [google](https://www.google.com.bd/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enBD651BD651&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=client%20object%20model%20in%20sharepoint%202010%20c%23), you will find so many ways to accomplish your goal.